# Comparar horário android

Tags: android, calendar

Possuo um cadastro onde o estabelecimento coloca seu horário de funcionamento em variáveis String, Ex: `horario_abertura` e `horario_fechamento` formato: **00:00 24hrs**.

Preciso que o aplicativo compare o horário atual com o de abertura e fechamento do estabelecimento, para informar se o mesmo está aberto ou fechado!

Alguém tem algum exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
public static final String inputFormat = "HH:mm";

private Date date;
private Date dateCompareOne;
private Date dateCompareTwo;

private String horarioabertura = "8:45";
private String horariofechamento = "18:45";

SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.US);

private void compareDates(){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    date = parseDate(hour + ":" + minute);
    dateCompareOne = parseDate(horarioabertura);
    dateCompareTwo = parseDate(horariofechamento);

    if ( dateCompareOne.before( date ) && dateCompareTwo.after(date)) {
        //esta aberto
    } else
        //esta fechado
}

private Date parseDate(String date) {

    try {
        return inputParser.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        return new Date(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, está comparando porém somente no formato 12hrs. Quando o horário ultrapassa o meio dia ele sempre está fechado.

Comment: Na verdade quando ultrapassa meio dia não entra no if

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.